# Javascript: in a string, replace the capital letter and all letters following it

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of strings, `dateTable, lastName, redColor` and I want to remove the capitalized letter and all letters after that, for example, remove Table, Name, and Color and leaving only date, last, and red. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done easily using `.replace()`:

```
"dateTable".replace(/[A-Z].*/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the letters and match them to a regex. Then use the sub string to get the string from start to index of the first upper case letter.

```
 var inputString = "What have YOU tried?";
var positions = [];
for(var i=0; i<inputString.length; i++){
if(inputString[i].match(/[A-Z]/) != null){
    positions.push(i);
break;

}
}
alert(positions);


var res = str.substring(1, postions[0]);

res should be the intended string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will alert what you wanted - you can continue from there
Check it:

```
function checkWord(word) {
  var foundFirst = false;
  var lengthToChop = 0;
  for (var i in word) {
     foundFirst = /^[A-Z]/.test( word[i])
     if (foundFirst){
        lengthToChop = i;
      break;
     }
  }
  alert(word.substring(0, lengthToChop));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fast non-regex loop that breaks at the first capital letter.

```
function strip(str) {
  var i = -1, out = [], len = str.length;
  while (++i < len) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 90) break;
    out.push(str[i]);
  }
  return out.join('');
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u4k0urzo/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code. No regular expressions... it should work and is pretty simple. Here is the fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/4ku3srjw/2/

Just replace the string for the variable word and you'll see it works for what you want

```
var word = "lastName";

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  if (word[i] === word[i].toUpperCase()) {
    var choppedWord = word.substr(0, i)
  }   
}
alert(choppedWord);
```

Hope it helps